# JavaFx - Method Undefined

Tags: java, methods, javafx

I have to create a program using JavaFX that creates a pane with a ball in it. There are four buttons that move the ball either left, right, up, or down. I don't understand why when I go to define each method (like .left() shown) the method call above remains an error that tells me it is undefined.

Main class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MoveTheBall extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        Circle circle = new Circle(20);
        circle.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circle.setFill(Color.WHITE);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle);

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(10);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Button btLeft = new Button("Left");
        Button btRight = new Button("Right");
        Button btUp = new Button("Up");
        Button btDown = new Button("Down");
        hBox.getChildren().add(btLeft);
        hBox.getChildren().add(btRight);
        hBox.getChildren().add(btUp);
        hBox.getChildren().add(btDown);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(pane);
        borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(hBox, Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 300, 200);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Move The Ball");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Buttons class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ControlBall extends Application {
    private MoveTheBall moveTheBall = new MoveTheBall();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setSpacing(5);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        Button btLeft = new Button("Left");
        Button btRight = new Button("Right");
        Button btUp = new Button("Up");
        Button btDown = new Button("Down");
        hBox.getChildren().add(btLeft);
        hBox.getChildren().add(btRight);
        hBox.getChildren().add(btUp);
        hBox.getChildren().add(btDown);

        btLeft.setOnAction(new LeftHandler());
        btRight.setOnAction(new RightHandler());
        btUp.setOnAction(new UpHandler());
        btDown.setOnAction(new DownHandler());

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(moveTheBall);
        borderPane.setBottom(hBox);
        BorderPane.setAlignment(hBox, Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 200, 150);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Move The Ball");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    class LeftHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            moveTheBall.left(); // error because no class yet
        }
    }

    class RightHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            moveTheBall.right(); // error because no class yet
        }
    }

    class UpHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            moveTheBall.up(); // error because no class yet
        }
    }

    class DownHandler implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            moveTheBall.down(); // error because no class yet
        }
    }
}

class moveTheBall extends StackPane {
    private Circle ball = new Circle(20);

    public moveTheBall() {
        getChildren().add(ball);
        ball.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        ball.setFill(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void left() {
        ball.setCenterX(-2.0);
        ball.setCenterY(-2.0);
    }
}
```

The line borderPane.setCenter(moveTheBall); is giving me problems as well. "The method setCenter(Node) in the type BorderPane is not applicable for the arguments (MoveTheBall)"

Comment: If you are going to down vote a post, at least comment why.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty new to JavaFX, but I'm gonna do the best I can here.

I would suggest instead of doing totally separate classes for controlling the ball, moving the ball, and handling each button, look into using lambda expressions to simplify the code and reduce your room for error. For example, you can set what the `btRight` button does by writing a line like this:

```
btRight.setOnAction(e -> {
    //if the ball is inside the right limit
        //Move the ball to the right
});
```

You can write these expressions directly into your `start()` method, and avoid defining inner classes, as well as a separate class for the control.

As far as why you are getting an error, my best guess (as i said, I'm new to this) is that `moveTheBall()` is a constructor for the MoveTheBall class, but it is being called as a method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I'll try it out and let you know. I seem to be alone in the woods. I can't find very many sources that help. Everything uses swing.